# jni passing class object as a parameter

Tags: java-native-interface, android-ndk

I have class which has an object of another class. When i pass that object to my jni function though jobject, the getFieldID says it cannot find the field. The variable name is definitely correct

```
jfieldID fidPopulation = (*env)->GetFieldID(env,cls,"mPopulation","I");
```

Comment: Any updates on whether you got this to work?

Comment: got a class not found exception. does it matter if class b is in a different package than class a ?

Comment: You should call findClass using the full package name path of the class. The package where A and B exist doesnt matter

Comment: so com.test.callactivity would be com/test/callactivity right ?

Answer (score 0):

In this function you are trying to access an integer type field called mPopulation. From your question it looks like you are trying to access an object field. "I" means that it is a integer. if you are trying to get some object, you should give its path some thing like "org/abc/MyClass"
 I am adding some code as per the comments below.
 objectA is passed by the JVM and is the object calling this function. objectB is a parameter and is an object of the class org/demopath/ClassB.java and is passed to test function from java.

```cpp
    Java_MyTestFunction( JNIEnv *env, jobject objectA, jobject objectB) {  
        jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "org/demopath/ClassB");  
        jfieldID fid = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, cls, "mPopulation ", "I");  
        jint population = (*env)->GetIntField(env, objectB, fid);  
    }
```

I have hand coded the signature so there might be some errors. Always use the generated signature

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Let me explain what I want to do. I have a class A which contains an object of class B which has a member mPopulation and some other members that I want to access from jni. The jni is function is called from class A. What do I do to access the object of class B in jni and its corresponding members ??

Comment: Since you are calling the JNI from an object of A, use that object which will be the 2nd parameter in the function signature. Get the fieldID of object b from within class A as I said above. Use that to get a reference to object B. Then use it to get the fields in B  See http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniref.html

Comment: Would that work even if object b was declared in a function of object A ??

Comment: No. You will have to pass that object to JNI as a function parameter. That will be easier

Comment: could you provide some code. I am not sure how to do the get field id of object part.